# Python - Remove first three chars' of string

Tags: python, string, integer, strip

So I have a super long string composed of integers and I am trying to extract and remove the first three numbers in the string, and I have been using the lstrip method (the idea is kinda like pop) but sometimes it would remove more than three.

```
x="49008410..."
x.lstrip(x[0:3])
"8410..."
```

I was hoping it would just remove `490` and return `08410` but it's being stubborn -_- .

Also I am running Python 2.7 on Windows... And don't ask why the integers are strings. If that bothers you, just replace them with letters. Same thing! LOL

Comment: `r, x = x[:3],x[3:]`

Comment: @BrenBarn If you're gonna mark me as duplicate, can you at least provide a link, so I am not going on a goose chase? Thanks!

Comment: check out the definition of lstrip.

Comment: Return a copy of the string S with leading whitespace removed.
    If chars is given and not None, remove characters in chars instead.
    If chars is unicode, S will be converted to unicode before stripping

Comment: In other words, you are removing x[0:3] from x.

Comment: @ChrisNguyen: The duplicate is linked at the top of your post.

Comment: Okay thanks for that. First time lol... And that definitely explains why it isn't working, and the mechanics of the strip attribute, but didn't completely help me out in terms of what to do lol. And I think @levi cracked this nut lol. And thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of remove the first 3 numbers, get all numbers behind the third position.  You can do it using `:` operator.

```
x="49008410..."
x[3:]
>> "8410..."
```

Comment: "x" doesn't have the attribute "length"... Or does it? O.o

Comment: Great Ceasers ghost! How did I not think of that? That works, thanks so much!